Health Connect permission view doesn't appear on Android < 14
I have a big problem:
On my Android (<14), it's impossible to show Health Connect permission view. The callback (below) is called directly:
private ActivityResultLauncher<String[]> mPermissionResult = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<java.util.Map<String, Boolean>>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(java.util.Map<String, Boolean> permissions) {
 ....
}

On logcat, I can see this message:
None of [android.permission.health.READ_WEIGHT, android.permission.health.READ_HEIGHT, android.permission.health.READ_TOTAL_CALORIES_BURNED, android.permission.health.READ_SLEEP, android.permission.health.READ_EXERCISE, android.permission.health.READ_STEPS] in {android.permission-group.NOTIFICATIONS=[android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS], android.permission-group.CONTACTS=[android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS], android.permission-group.READ_MEDIA_VISUAL=[android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES, android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO], android.permission-group.LOCATION=[android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION], android.permission-group.CAMERA=[android.permission.CAMERA], android.permission-group.PHONE=[android.permission.CALL_PHONE], android.permission-group.NEARBY_DEVICES=[android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN, android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE, android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT], android.permission-group.MICROPHONE=[android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO], android.permission-group.READ_MEDIA_AURAL=[android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO]}

I did some tests on Android 14+, and all works perfectly.
So, it's a problem linked with Health Connect permission on Android < 14.
Have you got some ideas guys?

You are requesting permissions with RequestMultiplePermissions, it works on Android 14 since Health Connect is part of Android 14 framework.
But on Android 13 or bellow, as your log said:
android.permission.health.READ_WEIGHT etc. are not in system's permission list

It's because Health Connect is a separated app on Android 13 or bellow.
To get it work, use Jetpack's Health Connect library:Get started with Health Connect.
And request permissions like the doc say:Step 4: Request permissions from the user.
Simple code for you:
// Create the permissions launcher
val requestPermissionActivityContract = PermissionController.createRequestPermissionResultContract()

val requestPermissions = registerForActivityResult(requestPermissionActivityContract) { granted ->
  if (granted.containsAll(PERMISSIONS)) {
    // Permissions successfully granted
  } else {
    // Lack of required permissions
  }
}

suspend fun checkPermissionsAndRun(healthConnectClient: HealthConnectClient) {
  val granted = healthConnectClient.permissionController.getGrantedPermissions()
  if (granted.containsAll(PERMISSIONS)) {
    // Permissions already granted; proceed with inserting or reading data
  } else {
    requestPermissions.launch(PERMISSIONS)
  }
}

